# Determinant of a symmetric matrix where the diagonal is the (negative) sum of all rows/columns, where one or two rows/columns are removed.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, symmetric-matrices

Since I have absolutely no idea how to research this, I guess I will ask it here to see if someone has a bright idea.

The problem background is calculating the resistance of a resistive network. Per [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/8306/), we have that;

$$ 
R_{kl} = \frac{\det(A_{kl})}{\det(A_l)}
$$

Here $R_{kl}$ is the effective resistance between node k and l. Here A is a matrix with the following properties:

$$A_{ij} = \begin{cases} \sum_{k \neq i} C_{ik} & i = j \\ -C_{ij} & i \neq j \end{cases}$$

Here $C_{ij}$ is the conductivity between node i and j, where C is defined as $R = \frac{1}{C}$.

Some observations:

- $A$ is a symmetric matrix
- The diagonal elements of the matrix are the (negative) sum of the rows/columns
- The determinant of A itself appears to be zero (I cannot prove this)
- When removing one row/column, we go back in "one dimension" of calculating the volume of a hypervolume.

I am using this on huge resistor networks. It would be nice to come up with some kind of trick to make calculating it easier. If any of you know a good approximation technique, or another good technique to calculate this determinant, that is also fine. I am currently creating a lower triangular matrix and then calculating the determinant by multiplying the diagonal elements.